# Pyramid grid in bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I was using Bootstrap3 to make a 3 column grid. That looks like this:

[image]

However, see those rows with just two boxes, and one box. I was wanting to experiment to see how it would look centered if there are not 3 full boxes.

I accomplished this by adding `display:flex; justify-content:center;` to the `.row` class but it's not the true bootstrap way. I was wondering what would be the true bootstrap way.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<div class="padd-80">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-0 col-md-4 col-md-offset-0 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-12">
      ....
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-0 col-md-4 col-md-offset-0 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-12">
      ....
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-0 col-md-4 col-md-offset-0 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-12">
      ....
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="padd-80">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-0 col-md-4 col-md-offset-0 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-12">
      ....
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-0 col-md-4 col-md-offset-0 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-12">
      ....
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="padd-80">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-0 col-md-4 col-md-offset-0 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-12">
      ....
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div class="padd-80">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-0 col-md-4 col-md-offset-0 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-12">
      ....
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-0 col-md-4 col-md-offset-0 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-12">
      ....
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-0 col-md-4 col-md-offset-0 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-12">
      ....
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="padd-80">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-4 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-12">
      ....
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-0 col-md-4 col-md-offset-0 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-12">
      ....
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="padd-80">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-12">
      ....
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Logic is simple, grid system of bootstrap consists of 12 columns.

If you have two divs, which are .col-lg-4, you should give col-lg-offset-2 to first div to make them centralised.

[2] [.col-lg-4] [.col-lg-4] [2]

For second row, I gave **col-lg-offset-2** and **col-md-offset-2** classes to first div.

For third row, I gave **col-lg-offset-4** and **col-md-offset-4** class to div.

[4] [.col-lg-4] [4]

Comment: Ohhh it's making more sense! Thank you very much! This worked!